# AWS API RunInstance is not using the ssh key-pair specified

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've found a very strange issue with AWS API, and this is not happening all the time.
Let me explain what I'm trying to achieve.

1. I've created a deployment procedure with node.js
2. The deployment procedure is used even by the application to deploy other instances from the script. So, the application once deployed to AWS, can deploy other instances in AWS by itself.
3. All communication is done through SSH and AWS API is used to create policies, key pairs, etc.
4. The private key of SSH used to connect to the Primary Server (master) stays on my PC. Let's say this key pair is "KEY-M". The private keys for the rest client instances (that are automatically deployed by the primary) stay on the primary server. Let's say this key pair is "KEY-C". So, two ssh key pairs are created by the application.

After deploying, The key pairs are correctly set and attached as shown in the AWS instances list:

That Is,

```
MASTER => KEY-M
CLIENT => KEY-C
```

But when I looked into the authorized_keys by connecting through the AWS interface, both the master and the client have the same content, i.e. public key of "KEY-M"

Below is the code to understand the run-instance method call for deployment:

```js
const deploy_key = await aws.createDeployKeyIfNotExists(region);

...
...

const run_config = {
    ImageId: image.ami_id,
    InstanceType: this.options.type || 't2.micro',
    MinCount: Math.max(this.options.number || 1, 1),
    MaxCount: Math.max(this.options.number || 1, 1),
    KeyName: deploy_key.name,
    AssociatePublicIpAddress: true,
    SecurityGroups: [security_group.GroupName],
};

const instances = (await aws.ec2(region).runInstances(run_config)).Instances;
```

Attached Keys
[image: Attached Keys]

Key Pairs
[image: Key Pairs]

Comment: is `run_config` used to deploy both master and client ?